# How to use mod_rewrite to get pages to appear as page1.html, page2.html etc?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've got the following 5 pages:

```
index.php?id=page1
index.php?id=page2
index.php?id=page3
index.php?id=page4
index.php?id=page5
```

And want to change them, using Mod Rewrite, into:

```
page1.html
page2.html
```

etc...

How to code that? I'm completely blue when it comes to .htaccess file. Thank you.

Comment: Please do add your tried htaccess file(there is nothing wrong or right we all here are here to learn) in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([^.]+)\.html$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,END]
```

For this to work you obviously need the rewriting module to be loaded into and activated inside your http server.

GBest is to place such rules inside the actual host configuration of your http server. On case you do not have access to that (so if you are using a cheap hosting provider) you can use a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), in that case the interpretation of such files for the host needs to be enabled inside the http server.

And a general advice: why would you want to use an old fashioned "file name extension"? That does not really make much sense these days. Why not use a URL without, so in the style of `https://example.com/some-page-title`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. About qour question - I am using this old technology for the recruitment process, so there is not much I can do about it.